# How can a Domain Model interact with UI and Data without being dependent on them?

Tags: orm, architecture, domain-driven-design

I have read there are *good design patterns* that resolve the following conflicting requirements: 1.) A domain model (DM) shouldn't be dependent on other layers like the UI and data persistence layers. 2.) The DM needs to interact with the UI and data persistence layers.  What patterns resolve this conflict?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure if you can call it a design pattern or not, but I believe that what you are looking for is the [Dependency Inversion Principle (DIP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle).

The principle states that:

> A. High-level modules should not depend on low-level modules. Both
>   should depend on abstractions.
>
> B. Abstractions should not depend on details. Details should depend on
>   abstractions. - [*Wikipedia*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle)

When you apply this principle to the traditionnal Layered Architecture, you end up pretty much with the widely adopted [Onion/Hexagonnal/Port & Adapters/etc...](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2013/12/03/layers-onions-ports-adapters-its-all-the-same/). architecture.

For instance, instead of the traditionnal `Presentation -> Application -> Domain -> Infrastructure` where the domain depends on infrastructure details you inverse the dependency and make the Infrastructure layer depend on an interface defined in the Domain layer. This allows the domain to depend on nothing else but itself.

> The DM needs to interact with the UI

About that, I cannot see any scenario where the domain should be aware of the UI.

Comment: Thanks plalx.  Naming that pattern (DIP) is helpful.  I can't vote up your answer yet, but when I can I'll come back and do so.

Answer (score 0):

This all really comes down to the use case of the software project. Use cases do not specify any sort of implementation in a project. You can do whatever you want, as long as you meet these specific project requirements.

There are fundamental building blocks that are necessary to meet these project requirements. For example, you cannot print a business report with last year's pencil taxes without having the actual number to print. You need that data, no matter what.

Then databases become the next level of implementation. Everything in the database is a fundamental building block that is required to complete the use case. You just simply cannot complete the use cases without it.

We don't want our users to just have a command line SQL program and do all the use cases by that, because that would take forever. Imagine every user having to know and understand the domain model behind your software, just to figure out what value to read to determine the font color of your title screen. Nobody is going to buy your software.

We may need more than a simply domain model to satisfy the use case from our customer. Let's build a program that will serve as a tool for the user to access the data, and update the data. We can simplify the knowledge and time required to perform this use case. For example, we can just make a button that loads the screen.

While the model, view, and controller are all viewed as being right next to each other on all the diagrams we see, they really belong stacked on top of each other. You can have a database without a view or a controller, but not vice versa. To build a view or controller, you must know what you are interacting with. You still need the fundamental pieces of data required to accomplish the purpose (which, you can find in the database).

Comment: Now, let me say this too.. you may need to store information in the database to aid you in presenting the information (titles, captions, etc). However, these then become part of the "critical information" that is required for your use case (ie, requirement says "must interact in a meaningful, user friendly way), and therefore become fundamental to the domain model.

Comment: What is your specific problem? Is there a particular case in which you can't seem to make the domain model independent?